# Nginx Ingress helm chart update from app version 0.21.0 to 0.22.0 --> No routing anymore

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, nginx-ingress

I have a pretty simple nginx ingress setup within the GKE by using the nginx-ingress helm chart:

```
helm install --namespace nginx-ingress-lb --name nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress --set rbac.create=true
```

All other apps which are also in other namespaces of course use this loadbalancer with the default annotation in each ingress.yaml:

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
```

Until chart version 1.1.5 and app version 0.21.0 everything was fine. But starting with chart version 1.2.0 and app version 0.22.0 the loadbalancer doesn't forward the traffic anymore. If I do a rollback to 0.21.0 again everything is fine. From my understanding the only thing that had a breaking change was

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target
```

which I don't use.

Any idea would be really appreciated since I don't wanna stick to app version 0.21.0.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you are using 0.22.0? The latest stable/nginx-ingress chart uses 0.23.0. There is a breaking change related to NGINX server listening on some port; perhaps that's worth a look? https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/Changelog.md

Comment: Hi! I tried 0.22.0 AND 0.23.0. Both don't work for me. Only 0.21.0 does.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more tests and it seemed to be an issue with my DNS provider. I let it run for a couple of hours and after a while it worked for some reason which is pretty odd. The only explanation I have is that the name resolution took longer than usual.